# Using external libraries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, oauth

I'd like to build a chrome extension in angular using AngularJS which interacts with Twitter.
I have some experience in integrating twitter with node.js but far less when it comes to angular only.

I'd like to use OAuth.js to connect to twitter (http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/) and therefore I was wondering how to integrate this with Angular?

Do I need to build a provider and rewrite all the function I need from OAuth.js or is there any quick way to do it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng oauth plugins that other people wrote like these:

- enginous/angular-oauth: 
  https://github.com/enginous/angular-oauth
- andreareginato/ng-oauth: 
  https://github.com/andreareginato/ng-oauth

I haven't used them myself, but documentation seems straight forward.

Comment: Is there any trick to wrap it inside a directive like there is to use d3.js in angular apps?

Comment: ng-oauth seems to offer directive style as shown under Example: <oauth ng-cloak
  site="siteUrlGoesHere"
  client="client-id"
  >Sign In</oauth>